# No RadialGradiantBrush and effects in WinRt

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

In WinRt there a clear lack of basic graphical effects and features that exists in all other Xaml based technologies, I'm not asking what's the solution to this problem, I'm asking rather what's the explanation of this lack ? Having the LinearGradiantBrush and not having the radial one is little bit not clear to me, some say it because of the Metro/ModernUI, whereas WindowsPhone also share that philosophy and still it has those features, what's the explanation to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that it might not fit the Microsoft Design Style it also can be extremely slow. From an [old but still relevant article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/01/15/maximizing-wpf-3d-performance-on-tier-2-hardware.aspx)

> Brush speed (fastest to slowest):
>
> 1. SolidColorBrush
> 2. LinearGradientBrush
> 3. ImageBrush
> 4. DrawingBrush (cached)
> 5. VisualBrush (cached)
> 6. RadialGradientBrush
> 7. DrawingBrush (uncached)
> 8. VisualBrush (uncached)

Comment: Very useful and interesting information, I thank you for that, but is it that slow that WinRT can't handle ? Dose that mean that WindowsPhone (which shares some WinRT now) is more powerful ??! WindowsStore Apps can bear many heavy things, how come it can't with these, regardless with the fact that these are really slow when compared in the hierarchy you mentioned.

Comment: WInRT is fast but a radial gradient is very slow. Windows Phone is older and more aligned to Silverlight. If you create a full screen radial gradient, potentially, the app has to calculate each and every pixel.

Comment: Got it for the brushes, what about effects ? is it the same explanation ??

Comment: Yes, I would guess so. A radial brush is 'just' pixel shader/effect.

Answer (score 1):

One Windows Runtime documentation I read said this about **RadialGradientBrush**:

> Windows Runtime does not have it. But if you fully embrace the
>   Microsoft Design Style then you might find that you don’t need it.

In short it's not recommended to be used in "Modern" Store apps because it does not fit the design guidelines. That's probably the reason it was not implemented in a first place for Windows 8 apps.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in my question, even if we consider that point, how come WindowsPhone has that, doesn't it share the same design style ??

Comment: That's because Windows Phone is based on Silverlight, that has it by default, but Windows 8.1 apps are based on Windows Runtime, that was designed from scratch with the requirements of modern apps in mind.